# How do I remove spaces from a column's value and make it lower case and then compare it with the parametre passed?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, string

Let's say I pass this parametre value  "aboutme" to my Stored procedure. In my table "PagesTable" I have a column named "PageName" that has values like "About Me" , "About Company", etc. Now what I want is compare the parametre passed (aboutme ie) with these column values. So I need to first convert the column values to lower case and remove the spaces in between and only then can I compare.

Someone please tell me how do you accomplish this in MSSQL? Any help will be greatly apreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Transforming the column value will mean that no indexes can be used. If this is a frequent search, and the table grows large, it could hurt performance. If this is likely, you might want to look into adding a computed column to the table, and indexing it.

Answer (score 5):

```
    DECLARE   @yourString   VARCHAR(100)
    SET   @yourString =   'HI HOW ARE YOU'

    SELECT LOWER( REPLACE( @yourString, ' ', '' ) )
```

For comparison against a value

```
    WHERE LOWER( REPLACE( ColumnName, ' ', '' ) ) = @val
```